# Using one typedef to use on two different data types in C?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

If I have a struct below, can I use void ** pointer if I don't know the type of object it will point to?

```
typedef struct A {
   ... many other things defined here 
   void ** pointer; 
};
```

If pointer array can be either int or struct, is it possible to encapsulate both in a single typedef above? The best solution I can think of is making two different typedefs, each accommodate either possibility:

```
typedef struct A {
   ... many other things defined here 
   struct A ** pointer_struct; 
   int ** pointer_int; 
};

typedef struct B {
   ... same many other things defined here 
   int ** pointer_int; 
};
```

Or a single struct that accommodate both possibility with either pointer_int or pointer_struct null:

```
typedef struct A {
   ... many other things defined here 
   struct A ** pointer_struct; 
   int ** pointer_int; 
} ;
```

Comment: Your `typedef` doesn't typedef anything.

Comment: Encapsulate them both in a `union { int **i; struct B **b; }`

Comment: You need to use a `union`.

Comment: Both `int **` and `struct A **` are convertible to `void *`, though not `void **`.

Comment: If I need the struct to occupy as little memory as possible, wouldn't union occupy more memory than defining two structs and doing some type checking at runtime to see which struct I need?

Comment: Yes you can use `void *` and assign a pointer to either struct to it. Your encapsulating struct would of course need to have some sort of type identifier in it so that you can know which struct pointer to cast the `void *` to (or some other means of determining the type).

Comment: a struct definition should not be 'typedef'd.   The result of such a typedef is cluttering the code, can (and often is) misleading,and clutters the compiler name space.  suggest using 'struct tagname' where ever a struct name needs to be referenced.  and remove the typedef modifer and name.

Comment: Union is a struct with all member's offsets equal to zero. Nothing more, so no overhead in space/time.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't think that's right. Any pointer can be converted to a pointer to a different object although it's UB if this results in a pointer that's not correctly aligned [6.3.2.3.7]. It's unlikely that "void \*" and "struct A\*" and "struct int\*" have different alignment requirements since they're all just pointers, so in practice the code is legal on any reasonable architecture.

Comment: @Anonymous: Alignment is irrelevant, here. Any object pointer can be safely converted to `void *` and back per 6.3.2.3.1. `void *` obviously has no alignment requirements of this kind at all, since there's no such thing as an object of `void` type. If you were talking about converting between an `int *` and a `struct A *` then 6.3.2.3.7 might be relevant, but that doesn't seem to be what the question is asking.

Comment: @user3629249: You've said that ("don't use typedef on structure definitions") before in comments to other questions.  I've disagreed with you before, because while there are some who will agree with you, there are also many who won't — me included.  And when I spot you making that comment without stating that it is an opinion and not everyone agrees with it, I will be obliged to counter-comment so that novices are not left with a false impression.